# In Python, is there a way to validate a user input in a certain format?

Tags: python, validation, user-input

In python, I'm asking the user to input an office code location which needs to be in the format: XX-XXX (where the X's would be letters)

How can I ensure that their input follows the format, and if it doesn't ask them to input the office code again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The standard (and language-agnostic) way of doing that is by using [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/):

```
import re

re.match('^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}$', some_text)
```

The above example returns `True` (in fact, a "truthy" return value, but you can pretend it's `True`) if the text contains 2 digits, a hyphen and 3 other digits. Here is the regex above broken down to its parts:

```
^     # marks the start of the string
[0-9] # any character between 0 and 9, basically one of 0123456789
{2}   # two times
-     # a hyphen
[0-9] # another character between 0 and 9
{3}   # three times
$     # end of string
```

I suggest you read more about regular expressions (or re, or regex, or regexp, however you want to name it), they're some kind of swiss army knife for a programmer.

Comment: Thanks, so if I needed it to be letters would I just use re.match('^[A-Z]{2}-[A-Z]{3}$', some_text)

Comment: if you only want uppercase letters, yes. If you also want lowercase letters you can use `[A-Za-z]`, or pass the [`IGNORECASE`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE") flag.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, you can use a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

```
import re
while True:
   inp = input() # raw_input in Python 2.x
   if re.match(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}$', inp):
       return inp
   print('Invalid office code, please enter again:')
```

Note that in many other cases, you can simply try converting the input into your internal representation. For example, when the input is a number, the code should look like:

```
def readNumber():
    while True:
        try:
          return int(input()) # raw_input in Python 2.x
        except ValueError:
          pass
```